# How would you translate the word "About" in a blog menu option?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, translation

I have to translate a site for a client and I came to the word "About". I could translate it as "Riguardo a", but is it the right translation in the context?

Comment: While is dedicated mainly to software, the Microsoft website [Language Portal](https://www.microsoft.com/language/it-it/default.aspx) is quite helpful in similar cases. There is also a style guide for every language.

Comment: @gabriele Well, as to Italian, I don't know, as to "every language"... the Russian Microsoft-made translations of interfaces are notoriously bad. Well, just a little warning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Commonly the standalone "about" in computer related texts is translated as "informazioni". It is far from litteral but is the most intuitive word for the Italian reader, and the one he is used to.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Usually, in commercial/institutional websites, the Engish title *About* (or *About us*) is translated into *Chi siamo* (or *Chi sono*, for individuals). The correspondence between *Chi siamo* and *About (us)* is made clear by launching a [web search in *Google*](https://www.google.it/search?q=chi%20siamo%20about%20us&biw=1215&bih=937&dpr=1&ei=_qVRVca2I8GsUa_ggNgH&emsg=NCSR&noj=1).

Answer (score 6):

I've seen also "su di me" if it's a single person and "su di noi" if it's a company. It gives more of a personal, approachable feeling.